# Unable to add Xamarin Google Play Services

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm unable to add GCM to my Xamarin app. This is the output from the package console:

```
Adding Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm...
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base (= 29.0.0.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (= 29.0.0.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (≥ 23.1.1.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measurement (= 29.0.0.1)'.
Updating 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.0.1.3' to 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.3.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.Forms' that is compatible with 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 23.3.0'.
```

Answer (score 3):

For this version you must install an earlier version of `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm`. I had no problems with `27.0.0`.

If you need the newest version, you could do this:

- uninstall xamarin.forms nuget package
- update all android packages to `23.3.0`
- install `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm`
- search for xamarin.forms and set in options `ignore dependencies`
- install newest version

Of course you must be aware of problems, since this is not recommended with good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Update your Xamarin.Forms package. Open Packages (Dropdown) in Solutions pane and Right-Click on Xamarin.Forms and click on Update

[image]

If you are using PCL, you can find this package in the PCL (Xamarin.Forms) project.

If you are using Shared Asset Project, you will find this package in both Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS project.

Comment: That did not work. There must have been some circular issue that prevented the package updates from working. In the end I had to remove Xamarin Forms then run update on packages to get newer version of MediaRouter then add Xamarin Forms back.

Comment: I removed all packages then re-added Xamarin Forms. Then attempted to add GCM. This is a version conflict that I believe Xamarin must fix. Please review the log here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kifib3u3ortk6zm/package.log

Answer (score 0):

You have to update Android SDK Platform-tools to revision 26.0.2 (or equivalent).

Open Android SDK Manager, check update, and select

"Update avaiable rev.26.0.2" and install it.

[image]